# MS Excel pivot table - expand column in a new sheet

Tags: excel, pivot-table

i wonder if this is possible at all or is there any way of expanding pivot table column in a new sheet.

here is what pivot i've got:
[image]

so you see it's grouped by customer.

the question is - can i expand/open each customer in a new sheet (as if you do when double clicking values)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out:

1. move Customers to filter (top left box)
2. then select a customer
3. double click on total values

   this will open all sales *ONLY* for selected customer

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Double click the Grand Total row *(for the Customer)*. If you don't have such then under PivotTable Options, Totals & Filters check Show grand totals for columns.

Comment: thanks for your comment. that will open ALL customers for that line. i actually figured out the answer. i will post here..